# How to Remove Line Numbers With A Dot At The End Of Number

Tags: regex

I have a large file with

1.ddgfhgf

a. asdf

b. sdaf

c. sadf

d. dsaf

546.asdf

a) hoihoij

b) dsfdsfa

c) fdghfgh

d) sdfggfhs

2.asffa

a) hoihoij

b) dsfdsfa

c) fdghfgh

d) sdfggfhs

789.adf

a) hoihoij

b) dsfdsfa

c) fdghfgh

d) sdfggfhs

3.adgag

a) hoihoij

b) dsfdsfa

c) fdghfgh

d) sdfggfhs

I need to remove the number and dot(.). Like following:

ddgfhgf

a. asdf

b. sdaf

c. sadf

d. dsaf

asdf

a) hoihoij

b) dsfdsfa

c) fdghfgh

d) sdfggfhs

asffa

a) hoihoij

b) dsfdsfa

c) fdghfgh

d) sdfggfhs

adf

a) hoihoij

b) dsfdsfa

c) fdghfgh

d) sdfggfhs

adgag

a) hoihoij

b) dsfdsfa

c) fdghfgh

d) sdfggfhs

I tryed `^([ \t]*)(\d+).[\t\b]` but it not work. I tryed ^[0-9]+ but can not remove the dot.

Comment: If it's not a regular expression question, change the tag to the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to use a programming language to replace the text.  Your example has the number and dot at the beginning of the line in each case.  It isn't clear if this is always the case so I wrote two.

This matches numbers and a dot that begin a line

```
/^\d+\./gm
```

This matches all cases of numbers prefixing a dot

```
/\d+\./gm
```

Comment: thanks for your support but it not work. I switched to regular expression and extended but not work. Try to support me! tks again!

Comment: It works well. Thanks so much. bcs i found /^\d+\./gm. When you send me link, i find ^\d+\. and it works. One more question: i removed the line number with dot but i still want to remove a space, two space or a tap or some tap to the begining character after the dot.

Comment: @Harper I'm not sure what you mean by a "tap or some tap".

This will remove spaces before or after the pattern.

http://regex101.com/r/fV8cU3/2

Comment: Hi TheNatureBoy, it works very well. Thanks you very very much. (tap or some tap: i mean the space that you use tap button on the keyboard when you want to make a blank bigger than a space key) tks again!

Answer (score 0):

```
^[ ]*\d+\.[ ]*
```

Try this.Repalce with `empty string`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/lZ5mN8/39

Comment: many tks but i only want to remove the number with dot and space after that. And Keep the words!

Comment: wow, it work too. But this can not remove space after the dot.